# Should we edit out "this is late but..." and other such late-answer opening prose

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Should we edit answers to remove these "stating I'm late" openings, which (IMO) add nothing to the answer?

- I know this is a tad late but
- I know this is an older question, but
- I am answering in case someone else runs across the question.
- Sorry for posting to an old thread

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's just as useless as "hello guys" and "okay, here is the solution," so yes. In general, it's safe to delete anything that doesn't add value.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically edit it? Manually, sure. We're busy people here. CHOP-CHOP